# Does Hive and HBase require running Hadoop Cluster?

Tags: amazon-s3, hive, hbase

This may be very basic question but I would like to know that for using queries in Hive and HBase, do we need a running Hadoop cluster?

I would like to use Hive or HBase with AWS S3 storage to store my data but wondering if I would need my cluster running all the time to be able to run queries as this would incur me cost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hive no, HBase yes, because it needs "a real filesystem". AWS EMR have done "things" to their version of HBase to work around this, but they've not shared that work with the open source code, so you only get it with EMR

Comment: Note: Azure WASB storage can support HBase direct; it's got the semantics HBase expects.

Comment: As hive converts the query to MapReduce job, then how does the MapReduce jobs gets run without hadoop cluster? Say, I have hive on S3, I run query on Hive, which gets converted to MapReduce, If I don't have a running cluster, how does this work?

Comment: you need something to execute the query. Qubole does something special there, but otherwise: you need 1+ machine capable of executing work. BTW, MapReduce is rarely used these days, Hive & Tez or Hive & LLAP;